# Defining multiple state variable inside a single component?

Tags: reactjs

I wish to make a  tag which have collapsible  inside it and then iterate the parent  over multiple time.  So that I close/open one does not affect the other .

Example:

```
data.map((data)=>{
 <div id="parent">
     <div>data.user</div>
     <div>
     {
        (this.state.open)===true ?
           <div id="child">data.userDetails</div>
          :  <div>{null}</div> 
      }
    </div>
   </div>
 })
```

I am looking to define dynamically "State Variable" . You can see I am mapping a Array and trying to read user Id. Once I click userId  then the "this.setState({open:true}) is called and user details are open.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Also: you tagged this question with react-native, but your code snippet only involves web html tags

Comment: I am looking to define dynamically "State Variable" . You can see I am mapping a Array and trying to read user Id. Once I click userId <div> then the "this.setState({open:true}) is called and user details are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it that way you should create a class user component and handle click action within it. That way every user component will behave independently to other.

```
data.map((data)=>{
   return <UserComponent user ={data.user} userDetails ={data.userDetails}/>
});
```

Than in your user component

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state{
      open:false
    }
    this.toggleDetails = this.toggleDetails.bind(this);
  }
  toggleDetails =()=>{
     this.setState((prevState)=>{open:!prevState.open});  //toggle Open state
  }
  render(){
    let {user, userDetails} = this.props //destructing of object
    return(
       <div id="parent" onClick ={this.toggleDetails}>
         <div>data.user</div>
          <div>
            {
             (this.state.open)===true ?
                <div id="child">userDetails</div>
                :  <div>{null}</div> 
            }
         </div>
       </div>
     );
    }
}
```

Comment: It run like a champ on production. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should keep unique indexes (or ids) of your opened elements in the state and implement click method which will update them.

**State object**

```
state = {
   openedElements: {}
}
```

**Data mapping**

```
data.map((el, idx) => {
 <div id="parent" onClick={this.toggleElement(idx)}>
     <div>{el.user}</div>
     <div>
      {
        this.state.openedElements[idx] &&
           <div id="child">{el.userDetails}</div>
      }
    </div>
   </div>
 })
```

**Toggle function**

```
const toggleElement = idx => {
    return () => {
       this.setState(prevState => {
           const { openedElements } = prevState
           return {
              ...openedElements, 
              openedElements[idx]: !openedElements[idx]
           }
       })
    }
}
```

*NOTE:* If you have `id` in your objects, it's better to use them instead of `idx` (`el.id`).

Comment: Thanks. I did not tried it as I found better solution from  Manjeet.

Comment: @ManasGond great!

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of when you would divide the current class into smaller other classes. If you `map` through data and for each iteration call another class, say.. `<DataCollapsible dataElement={data}/>`, you can store the boolean `open` in the class `DataCollapsible`.